# Unable to install perl module Crypt::DSA

Tags: perl, perl-module

I'm trying to install Perl module Crypt::DSA but it's not working. Unfortunately, there's nothing much i could find on Internet.

Here's the detail:

```
[root@jenkins_slave Crypt-DSA-1.17]# perl Makefile.PL
Generating a Unix-style Makefile
Writing Makefile for Crypt::DSA
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
[root@vpc-jenkins_slave3 Crypt-DSA-1.17]# make
Skip blib/lib/Crypt/DSA/Signature.pm (unchanged)
Skip blib/lib/Crypt/DSA/Key/SSH2.pm (unchanged)
Skip blib/lib/Crypt/DSA.pm (unchanged)
Skip blib/lib/Crypt/DSA/Util.pm (unchanged)
Skip blib/lib/Crypt/DSA/KeyChain.pm (unchanged)
Skip blib/lib/Crypt/DSA/Key/PEM.pm (unchanged)
Skip blib/lib/Crypt/DSA/Key.pm (unchanged)
Manifying blib/man3/Crypt::DSA.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/Crypt::DSA::Key.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/Crypt::DSA::Key::PEM.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/Crypt::DSA::Key::SSH2.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/Crypt::DSA::KeyChain.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/Crypt::DSA::Signature.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/Crypt::DSA::Util.3pm


[root@jenkins_slave Crypt-DSA-1.17]# make test
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 /usr/bin/perl "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-MTest::Harness" "-e" "undef *Test::Harness::Switches; test_harness(0, 'inc', 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/00-compile.t .. 1/1 # Testing Crypt::DSA 1.17
t/00-compile.t .. ok
t/01-util.t ..... ok
t/02-sign.t ..... ok
t/03-keygen.t ... ok
t/04-pem.t ...... 1/26 Use of uninitialized value $_[3] in abs at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Convert/ASN1/_encode.pm line 83.
Use of uninitialized value $_[3] in int at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/Convert/ASN1/_encode.pm line 92.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at /usr/share/perl5/Convert/PEM.pm line 102.

#   Failed test 'Load key using Crypt::DSA::key'
#   at t/04-pem.t line 46.
Can't call method "p" on an undefined value at t/04-pem.t line 47.
# Looks like you planned 26 tests but ran 7.
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 7 run.
# Looks like your test exited with 255 just after 7.
t/04-pem.t ...... Dubious, test returned 255 (wstat 65280, 0xff00)
Failed 20/26 subtests
t/06-fips.t ..... 1/9 # This takes a couple of minutes on slower machines.
t/06-fips.t ..... ok
t/07-openid.t ... 1/11
#   Failed test 'Parsed key'
#   at t/07-openid.t line 39.
Can't call method "p" on an undefined value at t/07-openid.t line 40.
# Looks like you planned 11 tests but ran 2.
# Looks like you failed 1 test of 2 run.
# Looks like your test exited with 255 just after 2.
t/07-openid.t ... Dubious, test returned 255 (wstat 65280, 0xff00)
Failed 10/11 subtests

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/04-pem.t    (Wstat: 65280 Tests: 7 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  7
  Non-zero exit status: 255
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 26 tests but ran 7.
t/07-openid.t (Wstat: 65280 Tests: 2 Failed: 1)
  Failed test:  2
  Non-zero exit status: 255
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 11 tests but ran 2.
Files=7, Tests=54, 464 wallclock secs ( 0.05 usr  0.05 sys + 21.05 cusr  0.19 csys = 21.34 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 2/7 test programs. 2/54 subtests failed.
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
```

I'm working on a Linux box. Any help will really be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `CPAN` or `cpanm`, or even your OS's package manager?

Comment: `t/04-pem.t` depends `Crypt::DES_EDE3` and `t/07-openid.t` depends on `Convert::PEM`: are they up-to date?

Comment: @Biffen: I tried CPAN first. When it failed then i tried installing the same manually. After reading your comment, i installed cpanm and tried installing the module but it failed with the same error.

Comment: @Biffen: When i tried running the RPM for Crypt::DSA, it failed for dependencies Math::GMP & Data::Buffer. These modules are already present on my system. Anyways, i tried downloading the RPMs for the same and i was able to install Data::Buffer but Math::GMP failed citing dependency for libgmp.so.3. On Googling, i found several suggestions such as creating sym link for the shared library file, creating file inside /etc/ld.so.conf.d with path to the .so file, etc. I tried those suggestions but nothing worked. It's still throwing the dependency error for libgmp.so.3 file.

Comment: @Matteo: Crypt::DES_EDE3 was up-to-date but Convert::PEM wasn't. After updating Convert::PEM module, Crypt::DSA installed successfully. Thanks a ton! I was really frustrated due to this. It was pending for last two days. You made my day! :)

Just one question: How did you figure out the culprits? I grepped the files for openid.t string and found it to be present in MANIFEST file only and the line was 't/07-openid.t'. Please enlighten me.

*** Also please post your comment as answer so that i can mark it. Thanks again! :)

Comment: @Technext It was just luck. I tried to install it myself and noticed that both tests were skipped since I did not have the dependencies. I just thought that it was then the most likely cause ...

Comment: Ok...so the install log mentioned the module names that it skipped? Anyways, please post your earlier suggestion as an answer because it 'did' help me resolve my issue.

Comment: Too localized.
This only happens on this one person's installation of linux; which he hasn't even specified which distro it is or which packages system he's using. Also it's been resolved in comments, but only through trial and error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Solved in the comments:*

Installing the module shows two dependencies for the following tests.

- `t/04-pem.t` depends on [`Crypt::DES_EDE3`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Crypt%3a%3aDES_EDE3)
- `t/07-openid.t` depends on [`Convert::PEM`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Convert%3a%3aPEM)

Make sure they are up to date